# I2c device not detected by Raspberry Pi

Tags: i2c

I recently bought a Dissolved Oxygen Kit from Atlas Scientific.

First I followed the instruction on the website to connect the device to my Raspberry Pi. This is my final result.

[image]

I then followed [this](https://www.atlas-scientific.com/_files/code/pi_sample_code.pdf) guide which shows how to enable the i2c display on the Raspberry Pi.

When I try to run the command `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` it should displays the information about the i2c devices connected. However, nothing shows up for me. I tried using another Raspberry Pi, different wires, even another i2c device but it definitely can't detect it.

I run the command `sudo nano /etc/modules` and added those two lines:

> i2c-bcm2708
>
> i2c-dev

I also try using `lsmod | grep i2c` to be sure that everything is loaded and it is.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is that LED green or blue?  If it's green then your unit is in UART mode.

Comment: It flashes green, then green and blue and loop.

Comment: I thought it was meant to be steady blue if it was set in I2C mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [joan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan) pointed out, it was indeed in UART mode so it is normal I could not detect it. More info [here](https://www.whiteboxes.ch/tentacle/i2c-or-uart/).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using recent software (last 6 months or so) you should be using device tree.

Add the line `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` to the file `/boot/config.txt`.

Remove the line `i2c-bcm2708` from `/etc/modules`.

Reboot.